# Programmatically call menu item with Eclipse JDT, Plug-In Development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I've been trying to figure out for a while now how to call an Eclipse menu item from within a plug-in that I'm developing. Say, for the sake of this posting, I want to call the eclipse "Format" menu item in the Right Click Menu to format a source, how would I go about doing this by calling that item (i.e. not just mimicking that menu item's effect, actually calling it)?

I'm not looking for how to format code, just simply the idea of calling a menu item.

I was leaning towards the APIs info on IWorkbench, Shell, ToolBar, ToolItem, etc., but I don't really know. I haven't been able to find anything on this topic in the APIs or anywhere else online. Is there a better approach to doing this rather than programmatically?

Eclipse JDT - http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=%2F3

EDIT:

```
String commandId = "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.format";
IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)(IHandlerService ) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
```

Simple as that. The hardest part is finding the commandId, which can be easily searched for, as rlegendi mentioned. This is exactly what I wanted. It accesses that plugin via ID, then executes it. Simple and effective. Thanks everyone!

Comment: "Is there a better approach" Yes, don't do it at all! GUI elements should not be triggered programatically. Instead, trigger the underlying functionality.

Comment: I figured, but how do I go about finding this functionality? There is a vast array of functions provided, but I'm not sure how to access that information. I don't feel that I should need to re-write code that is tried, true, and clearly available.

Comment: I know, it's not your fault. Eclipse is full of awful tightly coupled code. Hope some of that will be better in E4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but probably what you want to read about is the [Command/Delegate](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework) framework.

BTW if you install the *Eclipse Platform SDK* plugin (available by default), you can actually take a look on the source code of any plugin that is the part of your current Eclipse product (try `Ctrl+Shift+T` and typing `ISourceViewer` for instance, there you find the `FORMAT` it, for which you can do a search with `Ctrl+Shift+G`), and you can import any of those plugin projects to your own workspace to examine.

Comment: Awesome! this is getting me somewhere. I somehow have to tie multiple commands to one item, trying to figure that out at the moment, will post an answer once solved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Worked out great!